# Ubuntu on old MAC MINI 1.42 GHz /512/?

Tags: system-installation, mac, compatibility, macbuntu

I'm totally new in this subject... Is there a possibility to install Ubuntu on an old MAC MINI 1.42 GHz | 512 | without INTEL processor?

- If not does anybody have an idea for another system/OS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

- Is about [Ubuntu 12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1961136). Problems with sound after install.
- Is about [Ubuntu 10.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=960914). Old but has comment about partitioning outside of Ubuntu installer (no idea if this is current).
- [Proof 3](http://herbert-janssen.de/mac-mini-g4-faq.html). See remark #12 (he advices to install lUbuntu).